# Quartz.NET - Determine if last job was faulted

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET and generate some statistics within a job.
Quartz is using the database for storing its triggers and jobs.

For generating the stats, I am using the last execution time since now as date range.

I now want to know if the last run was successful or throwed an exception. I cannot store this information in the database myself.

Do I get this information from Quartz?

Comment: As i can see, Quartz did not support this information, you need to collect this by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I added the attribute `[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]` and store the data in the `context.JobDetail.JobDataMap`. This allows me to get a value which is stored in the database of Quartz.